# Resampling HTMLImageElement for animation

Tags: html5-canvas, webgl

An HTMLVideoElement can be resampled in order to get different frames into a texture over time.

For example, as shown at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Animating_textures_in_WebGL

However- when loading an animated gif into a HTMLImageElement, resampling does not show the updated texture. This is true even if the image is mounted on the dom and the different frames show on that copy.

Is there a standard way to display an animated gif in webgl, or must it be somehow rewritten into a spritesheet (or series of textures) at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GIFs aren't automatically animated with WebGL (or regular canvas for that matter) and there is no standard way of doing this.

Contrary to video elements GIF images will only draw the *first* frame via `drawImage()` while drawing video elements will draw current frame. This is in part because we don't really have access to any of the image's frames via API (this also applies to animated PNG files, aka APNG) and animated images will be handled only as an internal process conducted at the discretion of the browser and only when in DOM.

With video elements though we do have access to "frames", that is, time via `currentTime` so it's sort of implies that we want to deal with what we see or what exist at the current time.

You have to manually animate a GIF image though. This means you have to extract each frames as separate images/buffers first then show them at the rate you chose. The browser won't help you a bit here, but you can do this by parsing the file format manually.

Of course, this can be a bit tedious, but luckily there are people out there that has done all the lifting and hard work. For example [gifuct](https://github.com/matt-way/gifuct-js) (I have not tested it myself but there are others out there as well) will allow you to extract each frame from a GIF

Then render each frame you got from that into the frame buffer and upload to the GPU at the frame rate you choose.

Or:

- pre-process the GIF into a spritesheet as you mention
- or load it as an image sequence instead
- or convert the GIF to a video (this may even reduce the total size)

And as a shameless plug if you should consider APNG instead: I have made [apng-parser](https://github.com/epistemex/apng-parser) which does the same for APNG files.

**My recommendation** though is to convert the GIF/APNG to a video file which gives the animation capabilities for free, potentially smaller files, can be buffered and streamed for long animations, less code to include and typically a single file to deal with (you may have to provide different video formats for older browsers). Free software such as [FFMpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) can help you with the conversion.

Comment: Thanks! If it were up to me it would definitely be video for long animations and spritesheet for short ones... unfortunately I need to support a legacy system here :\